# Join ONE column to another table in a SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull the 'name' column from a table called ps_product_lang. My current SQL statement without the JOIN is:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT reference, price FROM ps_product_attribute WHERE id_product = ". implode(' AND ', $_POST['checkbox']) ."");
```

Here is my Statement with the **join:**

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ps_product.id_product as id_product, reference, price, name LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product_lang.id_product = ps_product.id_product WHERE id_product = ". implode(' AND ', $_POST['checkbox']) ."");
```

The **error** I am getting is:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT
>   command denied to user 'removed'@'localhost' for table 'id_product'

Why is this?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: That's not how you write a join. When you put `FROM ps_product.id_product`, that means, the `id_product` table in the `ps_product` database. You should put your desired columns in the `SELECT` portion of your query, not the `FROM` portion.

Comment: It seems the user does not have the permission to execute the 'SELECT' statement in the database. It also seems you're trying two databases, but forgot to add the database reference in the join? That may be causing your problem (or it's the from part)... ;)

Comment: @PatrickQ where have I gone wrong? It isn't to do with permissions as it works fine without the join.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this part to do `WHERE id_product = ". implode(' AND ', $_POST['checkbox']) .""`? I can almost guarantee that whatever it is, it's not right.